# Informatica error message 'Aggregate functions are not allowed in variable port'

Tags: informatica

I am new to the aggregator transformation and pretty new to alot of the transformations.
I have done some really straightforward ones... it seems like because it is so straightforward it should work. i have the variable box checked in the port, and the expression is count(names)... i wanted to use it as a variable and compare the result, once  it is in the variable field. It is defined as a decimal... it will work in an output port.. but I need to do more with it as a  variable... the guide said thaat count can be used in the variable port... the expression is count(name)... Name of the field is name_variable.. your help is much appreciated.. thank you.

Comment: a screenshot of the mapping will help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Aggregator Transformation` to use aggregate functions (COUNT, MAX, MIN, etc.). From the description it seems you've tried using COUNT function in variable port of `Expression Transformation` - this will not be allowed.